# How do I include an activeX library in my C++ project?

Tags: c++, dll, activex

I would like to add a third party library to my C++ project.
The library is ActiveX and I have to admit, that I have no experience with that. I tried to google the solution but could not find one that fits for me.
I'm using Visual Studio and my project is not MFC.

From the third party library I have a dll-file, a tlb-file and an idl-file, but no header file. I tried to include the tlb-file but when compiling I got a lot of errors from the kind of `missing typedef for default-int` and `character is not allowed`. (just by writing `#include "xyz.tlb"`)

Is the tlb file incompatible with my project? Is there another way to include the activeX class I need?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could easily write an entire college course about doing what you're talking about. The simple answer is that you need to use `#import` not `#include`, but there is a *lot* more you'll have to deal with to properly utilize an activex library.